# Daypilot's scheduler control in asp.net MVC 3 thowing exception "The request must start with JSON "

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, scheduler

I wanted a scheduler control that work in ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor view engine. I came across the DayPilot open source Lite edition. I just followed the sample example from their site but i cannot make my sample work. It throws the exception "The request must start with JSON". The sample works perfectly in my machine.

Can someone help me in resolving this issue ?

I am open to using other schedulers also.

Comment: You are trying to open the backend URL in the browser. See here: http://forums.daypilot.org/Topic.aspx/1641/error---the-request-must-start-with-json-string

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking into a similar scheduling solution, check [DHTMLX Scheduler .NET for ASP.NET](http://scheduler-net.com/)
There is a detailed [tutorial](http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/2012/03/15/asp-net-event-calendar-mvc3-razor.aspx) on how to implement it with MVC3 Razor.